# 3D cube animation transition with more than four elements

Tags: css, animation, 3d

I try to create an animation like the animation on `mac` for a carousel. 
I tried to use a 3D cube as the base, but I don't find a way to ad more than four elements in the carousel without broke the animation.

```css
.wrap {
  perspective: none;
  perspective-origin: 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  color : white;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: center left;
}


.front {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.cube {
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front">front</div>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**i try This code** :     https://jsfiddle.net/Goby03/jxm8c2ob/

[image]

Comment: If you add more surfaces (div in this case), you need to calculate and update your other div values again and again as you keep on increasing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make 3D cube animation like this one:

```css
  .stage {
    width: 120px; 
    height: 120px;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    from,to  { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    16%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);                           }
    33%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);            }
    50%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);           }
    66%      { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);           }
    83%      { -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);                            }
  }

  @keyframes spincube {
    from,to {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
      transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    16% {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
      transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    33% {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    }
    50% {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    }
    66% {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
      transform: rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    83% {
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
      transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
  }

  .cubespinner {
    -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;

    animation-name: spincube;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 12s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
    transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
  }

  .cubespinner div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: blue;
    line-height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .cubespinner .face1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(60px);
    transform: translateZ(60px);
  }
  .cubespinner .face2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
  }
  .cubespinner .face3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
  }
  .cubespinner .face4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
  }
  .cubespinner .face5 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
  }
  .cubespinner .face6 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="stage">
<div class="cubespinner">
<div class="face1">1</div>
<div class="face2">2</div>
<div class="face3">3</div>
<div class="face4">4</div>
<div class="face5">5</div>
<div class="face6">6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Hope it's what you're looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var carouselCustomeTemplateProps =  {
      width: 400,     /* largest allowed width */
     height: 300,     /* largest allowed height */
     slideLayout : 'fill',     /* "contain" (fit according to aspect ratio), "fill" (stretches object to fill) and "cover" (overflows box but maintains ratio) */
     animation: 'slide3D',  /* slide | scroll | fade | zoomInSlide | zoomInScroll */
     animationCurve: 'ease',
     animationDuration: 1900,
     animationInterval: 2000,
     slideClass: 'jR3DCarouselCustomSlide',
     autoplay: true,
     controls: true,   /* control buttons */
     navigation: ''   /* circles | squares | '' */,
     perspective: 200,
     rotationDirection: 'ltr',
     onSlideShow: slideShownCallback
      
  }
 function slideShownCallback($slide){
  $slide.find('img').attr('src')
 }

 jR3DCarouselCustomeTemplate = $('.jR3DCarouselGalleryCustomeTemplate').jR3DCarousel(carouselCustomeTemplateProps);

  })
```

```css
.jR3DCarouselGalleryCustomeTemplate {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.jR3DCarouselGalleryCustomeTemplate .captions{
 position: relative;
 padding: 4px 0;
 bottom: 27px;
 background: #000;
    color: #fff;
 display:block;
    text-align: center
}
.jR3DCarouselGalleryCustomeTemplate a{
 text-decoration: none;   
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vinayakjadhav/jR3DCarousel/v1.0.0/dist/jR3DCarousel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="jR3DCarouselGalleryCustomeTemplate">
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=838" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <a href="http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jR3DCarousel/" target="_blank">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=839" />
     <span class="captions">This is clickable slide 2</span>
    </a>    
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=823" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=836" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=838" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=832" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="jR3DCarouselCustomSlide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/450?image=837" />
    <div class="captions">This is custom text slide 5</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I am looking for. But thank you anyway.
I want to make a carousel which switch content from right to left with a 3D cube animation.

Comment: Ok. I understood. I'll try to help you about ;)

Comment: Yes ! It's exactly what I want! Thank you very much! Your awesome !